# Problem with Dell TEAC CAB-200 installed 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I can not get it to recognize my bluetooth adapter. I know the computer can use the adapter because my keyboard is working,but Ubuntu tells me I have no adapters and so I can not connect anything else.

I have tried using `hid2hci` which just keeps timing out. I'm at a complete loss and Google has not helped. Any suggestions would be great. I should mention that I've only been running Linux for a couple of months, I am capable but in no way an expert.

This is what shows up in 'usb-devices'

```
T: Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#= 4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=0644 ProdID=0201 Rev=07.12
S: Manufacturer=DELL
S: Product=CAB-200
S: SerialNumber=000001178131
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=98mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the Bluetooth device drivers :

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

Then run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluez-utils restart
```